# Find all positive integers $n$ for which $1372n^4 - 3 $ is an odd perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, perfect-powers

> > Find all positive integers $n$ for which $1372\,n^4 - 3$ is an odd perfect square.

I tried $\bmod ,4,5,7$ and failed. Next, I used Vieta’s Theorem and failed again.

Any hints, please. Thank you very much!

Edit number and parity already. Sorry for typo

Edit 2 : This question is related to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774415/find-all-n-which-7n2-n-1-is-perfect-4th-power)

Comment: I think it has to do with the pell type equation $k^2-7x^2=-3$

Comment: try to write $n^4=(1+(n-1))^4$ and expand it? Expand odd perfect square as (2k+1)^2, too. That may help?

Comment: @IvartheBoneless This question appears to come from your previous one of [Find all $n$ which $7(n^2 + n + 1)$ is perfect $4^{th}$ power.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3774415/602049) where multiplying both sides of your equation $n^2 + n + 1 = 343k^4$ gives $4n^2 + 4n + 4 = 1372k^4$, which becomes $(2n+1)^2 + 3 = 1372k^4$, so $1372k^4 - 3$ is equal to an odd perfect square, i.e., $(2n+1)^2$. Please provide a link & such details in the future to help people better understand the context of what you're asking, as well as to help avoid things like duplication of efforts across questions.

Comment: Oh , sorry. @JohnOmielan

Comment: I'm not sure any of the "answers" so far fully answers this question

Comment: Just to better target the search of a solution: is this question taken from a contest or a book (so that the existence of a formal proof is highly probable) or is it only a conjecture based on observations and brute-force computations?

Comment: It is on my school worksheet. The teacher just say that only $n = 1$ is the solution.  So I want to know whether only $1$ is the answer or there are more answers.

Comment: @IvartheBoneless n=1 is the only positive answer. See my solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $y^2=1372x^4-3$ has only one positive integral solution for $x$ and $y$ at which is found at $(1,37)$.

We can use the general technique in this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/338108 to convert your quartic into Weierstrass form and then we can use MAGMA to find all integral points on the curve.

**Step 1: Quartic to Cubic (Weierstrass form)**

$y^2=1372x^4-3$ can be transformed into $Y^2=X^3-4116X$ using $X:=1372x^2$ and $Y:=1372xy$ via the steps below

Take
$$y^2=1372x^4-3$$
Multiply both sides by $1372^2x^2$
$$1372^2x^2y^2=1372^3x^6-3\times1372^2x^2$$
$$(1372xy)^2=(1372x^2)^3-(3\times1372)(1372x^2)$$
$$Y^2=X^3-4116X$$

**Step 2: Search for Integral Points**

Then using MAGMA (An online version is here for you to confirm my work for yourself: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) we can run the following two lines of code to find all of the integral points on our curve:

```
E := EllipticCurve([0,0,0,4116,0]);
IntegralPoints(E);
```

And we get the result: $(0 : 0 : 1)$ which tells us that the only one solution exists (the one that we found manually $(1,37)$).

**Alternatively: Easier Solution**

We could also run the following to get this answer directly (I realized this command existed after doing the work above, but it confirms the same answer).

```
IntegralQuarticPoints([1372, 0, 0, 0, -3]);
```

which gives the only positive output as $[ 1, 37 ]$

Answer (score 1):

The function: $\sqrt{1372n^4 - 3}$ produces one integer only: when $n = 1$, it produces $37$.

For $ n \geq 2$, the function produces decimals.

Therefore, there is no positive integer $n$ such that $1372n^4 - 3$ is a odd perfect square.

This is a brute force function that I tested out on Python - ran the code till $10000$.

Comment: This may be true (though $n=1$ is a positive integer so I guess you only consider $n>1$), but it's not obvious.  How do you prove it?

Comment: Formatting:  you need to surround the argument of the sqrt function with { } if you want to extend the radical over the whole thing.  Thus...\sqrt {1372n^4-3} works.

Comment: @lulu, it's a brute force function - I tested it on Python up to $10000$ and it only produces an integer when $n = 1$.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for the formatting help.

Comment: Ok, but that is not a proof.  Perhaps $n=10^4+1$ is a solution, who knows?  I agree it is numerical evidence but it isn't a proof...you should edit your post to indicate that.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for the formatting help.

Comment: @lulu, tried $ n = 10^4 + 1$, didn't work.

Comment: @lulu, I am also working on a proof to show that this is true without Python. Can you help me, please?

Comment: The proof sketched by mathmasterzach below is the standard argument.  The other proposed proof here appears (to me) to be incomplete though perhaps there is a way to patch it up.  Anyway, it is certainly worth studying the standard argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another way.

$1372n^4=m^2+3\Rightarrow2n^4\equiv m^2+3\pmod{10}$.

Noting $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z_{10}$ we have
$$\mathbb Z_{10}^4=\{1,6,5,0\}\Rightarrow2\mathbb Z_{10}^4=\{2,0\}\\\mathbb Z_{10}^2=\{1,4,9,6,5,0\}\Rightarrow\mathbb Z_{10}^2+3=\{4,7,2,9,8,3\}$$

Since $2\mathbb Z_{10}^4\cap(\mathbb Z_{10}^2+3)=\{2\}$ we deduce that modulo $10$ we must have $n=1$ which corresponds to $m=7$ (*because of $7^2+3\equiv2\pmod{10}$*).

It follows that the only solution is $n=1$.

Comment: also $3^2+3\equiv2\bmod10$; and just because $n\equiv1\bmod10$ doesn't mean $n=1$

Comment: $n=10N+1$ but this works just for $N=0$ and corresponds with $m=10M+7$ for $M=3$ if I remember well.